# why node js server is sending cookie to postman and not to react app at localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, request

Below code is sending data and token to app but not cookie or may be it is not accepted by browser  as everthing is working fine with postman.

Node js code (related to cookie)

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });
};

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
  };
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") cookieOptions.secure = true;

  res.cookie("jwt", token, cookieOptions);
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: "success",
    token,
    data: { user: user },
  });
};
```

React code (related to request)

```
function Signin() {
  const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login/";
  const header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  const [data, setdata] = React.useState({});

  const handle = (e) => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setdata(newData);
  };
  const sendData = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
    axios({ method: "POST", url: url, data: data, headers: header })
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
}
```

Comment: Secure cookies can only be sent with https - your client is requesting via http

Comment: Also, Axios probably requires the `withCredentials` option be set in order to include cookies with the request.